# How to stop Keyframe Animation after users login?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, keyframe

I added keyframe animation to my login icon. Its purpose is to attract the attention of unregistered users. But I want the keyframe animation to stop once users log in to the site. The idea is only to work when ghosts/non-register users visit the site.

That's the code i've used in my style.css. My site is running on Wordpress.

```
.menu-item-15097 .dashicons-download {
    animation-name: menu-item-15097;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes dashicons-download {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px grey;
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px grey;
    }
}
```

I will hope for a detailed explanation of how to do it. Which files will I need to edit with correct element for me. I guess i will need to add additional code to my style.css and maybe some javascript too?

Comment: are you using php to login?

Comment: My site is running on Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

Assign this animation to a className.
Define this class for the tag
Once the user login, delete that class with JavaScript

html:

```
<tag-name class="element_class animate_class">..</tag-name>
```

css:

```
.animate_class {
    animation-name: menu-item-15097;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

javascript (run after login):

```
document.querySelector(".element_class").classList.remove("animate_class")
```

you can see the sample in here
[codepen.io/kazemi](https://codepen.io/kazemi/pen/BawYrzM)

Comment: I apologize for the lack of knowledge. My animation element should be `.menu-item-15097 .dashicons-download`, otherwise won't work. And how to target that javacode to stop animation when you are logged in? What changes needs to be done to run after login? Just copy-paste what you have gave does not work. And i have tried this too - `document.querySelector(".menu-item-15097 .dashicons-download").classList.remove("menu-item-15097")`

Comment: please add your code in codepen.io and send me your pen url. then i can help you to resolve it

Comment: I'm pretty new to everything. I hope i've done it correctly. Here is the link  - [link](https://codepen.io/tikarsvt-the-sasster/pen/RwLQKYv)

Comment: see the link in my answer

Comment: I've copy-paste your code, but the animation does not work at all. From what i can see, if the element selector isn't exactly `.menu-item-15097 .dashicons-download` it won't work. I've tried this, but still does not work for logged users - [link](https://codepen.io/tikarsvt-the-sasster/pen/RwLQKYv)

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
/* element name */.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
```

in your javascript after the user logs in.

Or if you want to use css only:

```
/* element selector */ {
    animation-play-state: paused
}
```

To pause your animation.

Reference:
https://css-tricks.com/how-to-play-and-pause-css-animations-with-css-custom-properties/

Comment: How you target this code to work to logged in users?

Comment: you should have an id, added by js, for the element for the logged in users

Comment: More detailed help, how that code would looke like?